# Cannot read properties of undefined belongsToMany in sequelize

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I am developing a project using Node.js, Sequelize, and TypeScript, but I am getting the following error messages when configuring the N:N relationship between the Sales and Products tables:

`Products.belongsToMany(Sales, { TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'belongsToMany')`

and

`Sales.belongsToMany(Products, { TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'belongsToMany')`

I have 4 tables: `users`, `products`, `sales`, and `salesProducts`. The relationship between the sales and products tables with the `salesProducts` table is N:N.

When I make the association within the `salesProducts` table, the following error is displayed: `"error": "products is not associated to sales!"`

And when I make the association within the sales and products tables, the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'belongsToMany')` is displayed.

Below I will provide the file configurations.

I have the file **database/config/database.ts**

```
import "dotenv/config";

const config = {
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
  dialect: "mysql",
  dialectOptions: {
    timezone: "Z",
  },
  logging: false,
};

module.exports = config;
```

I have the file **database/models/index.model.ts**

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
import * as config from '../config/database';

export default new Sequelize(config);
```

I have the file **database/models/products.model.ts**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';
import Sales from './sales.model';
import SalesProducts from './salesproducts.model';

class Products extends Model {
  declare id: number;
  declare name: string;
  declare type: string;
  declare price: number;
  declare quantity: number;
  declare url_image: string;
}

Products.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  type: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
  price: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  quantity: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
  url_image: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: true },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'products',
  timestamps: false,
});

Products.belongsToMany(Sales, {
  as: 'sales',
  through: SalesProducts,
  foreignKey: 'productId',
  otherKey: 'saleId',
});

export default Products;
```

I have the file **database/models/sales.model.ts**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';
import Users from './users.model';
import Products from './products.model';
import SalesProducts from './salesproducts.model';

class Sales extends Model {
  declare id: number;
  declare userId: string;
  declare sellerId: string;
  declare totalPrice: number;
  declare saleDate: Date;
  declare statusSale: string;
}

Sales.init({
  id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
  userId: DataTypes.STRING,
  sellerId: DataTypes.STRING,
  totalPrice: { type: DataTypes.DECIMAL, allowNull: false },
  saleDate: { type: DataTypes.DATE, defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW },
  statusSale: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'sales',
  timestamps: false,
});

// Relationship between the sales and users tables.
Users.hasMany(Products, {
  foreignKey: 'id',
  as: 'saleId'
})

Sales.belongsTo(Users, {
  foreignKey: 'userId',
  as: 'user_id'
})

// Relationship between the sales and salesProducts tables.
Sales.belongsToMany(Products, {
  as: 'products',
  through: SalesProducts,
  foreignKey: 'saleId',
  otherKey: 'productId',
});

export default Sales;
```

i have the file **database/models/salesProducts.ts**

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from 'sequelize';
import db from './index.model';
import Products from './products.model';
import Sales from './sales.model';

class SalesProducts extends Model {
  declare saleId: number;
  declare productId: number;
  declare quantity: number;
  static associate: (models: any) => void;
}

SalesProducts.init({
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  saleId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: { model: 'sales', key: 'id' },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    field: 'sale_id',
  },
  productId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    references: { model: 'products', key: 'id' },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    field: 'product_id',
  },
  quantity: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
  underscored: true,
  sequelize: db,
  modelName: 'salesProducts',
  timestamps: false,
});

// If the association between tables occurs here, the error "error": "products is not associated to sales!" appears.

// Products.belongsToMany(Sales, {
//   as: 'sale',
//   through: SalesProducts,
//   foreignKey: 'productId',
//   otherKey: 'saleId',
// });

// Sales.belongsToMany(Products, {
//   as: 'products',
//   through: SalesProducts,
//   foreignKey: 'saleId',
//   otherKey: 'productId',
// });

export default SalesProducts;
```

I tried to make the associations directly in the salesProducts model, but the error changes to the one commented in the code inside the file I sent in salesProducts.ts.